# Overlapping table entry

Tags: tables, multirow

When using multirow, the entry overlaps to other columnn

[image]
Here is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |} \hline
    Phases & Input & Process & Output \\ \hline
    Phase 1 Acquisition of DNS query logs & DNS queries from MSU-IIT campus network & Name resolution via an existing DNS server & DNS query logs \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Phase 2 Development of the domain name recommendation engine} & DNS query logs & Co-occurrence transformation & Co-occurrence matrix \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Co-occurrence matrix & Self-organizing feature map training & Transaction clusters \\ \cline{2-4} \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text argument of `\multirow` is put into an `\hbox`, if used with `*` for the width. `\parbox` and friends can be used to get a multi line text entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |} \hline
    Phases & Input & Process & Output \\ \hline
    Phase 1 Acquisition of DNS query logs & DNS queries from MSU-IIT campus
    network & Name resolution via an existing DNS server & DNS query logs \\
\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{%
      \parbox{3cm}{\RaggedRight
        Phase 2 Development of the domain name recommendation engine}%
    } & DNS query logs & Co-occurrence transformation & Co-occurrence
        matrix \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Co-occurrence matrix & Self-organizing feature map training &
Transaction clusters \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without hyphenation the entry is one line too long, therefore the example uses `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`.

It is easier to use `3cm` instead of `*` in the argument of `\multirow`. Then the text is automatically set as multi line entry. The *`<fixup>`* argument moves the entry, thus that five lines fit into the space and hyphenation is no longer necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}% 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |} \hline
    Phases & Input & Process & Output \\ \hline
    Phase 1 Acquisition of DNS query logs & DNS queries from MSU-IIT campus
    network & Name resolution via an existing DNS server & DNS query logs \\  
\hline
    \multirow{2}{3cm}[1.25ex]{%
       \raggedright
        Phase 2 Development of the domain name recommendation engine%
    }
    & DNS query logs & Co-occurrence transformation & Co-occurrence
        matrix \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Co-occurrence matrix & Self-organizing feature map training &
Transaction clusters \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Variant with package `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{L{3cm} L{3cm} L{3cm} L{3cm}}
    \toprule
    Phases & Input & Process & Output \\
    \midrule
    Phase 1 Acquisition of DNS query logs & DNS queries from MSU-IIT campus
    network & Name resolution via an existing DNS server & DNS query logs \\
    \midrule
    \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L{3cm}@{}}
        Phase 2 Development of the domain name recommendation engine%
    \end{tabular}}
    & DNS query logs & Co-occurrence transformation & Co-occurrence
        matrix \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & Co-occurrence matrix & Self-organizing feature map training &
      Transaction clusters \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result booktabs]

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a `tabularx` environment, and put the contents of `\multirow` in a `\parbox` of the size of the `X` columns (`\hsize`). I added the `cellspace` package to have some vertical padding for the rows, and the `boldline` package (from the `shipunov` bundle) to have variable-width line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx, caption}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\renewcommand\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\renewcommand\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}\\

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-1.75em}{V{2}*{3}{S{X}|}S{X}V{2}}
    \hlineB{2.5}
    \textbf{Phases} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Process} & \textbf{Output} \\
    \hlineB{1.6}
    \textbf{Phase 1}: Acquisition of DNS query logs & DNS queries from MSU-IIT campus network & Name resolution via an existing DNS server & DNS query logs \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}[0.75ex]{\parbox{\hsize}{\RaggedRight\textbf{Phase 2}: Development of the domain name recommendation engine}} & DNS query logs & Co-occurrence transformation & Co-occurrence matrix \\
    \cline{2-4}
  & Co-occurrence matrix & Self-organizing feature map training & Transaction clusters \\
    \hlineB{2.5}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]